# What does the term "supercharge" mean in the given sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence from a game's description:

> Supercharge your Friends of the Universe base.

It is the description of a combat game in which players can make teams to take on their rivals. The game gives monthly challenges and players get rewards and perks once they complete their challenges.

For confidentiality reasons, I cannot share more details here.

Comment: Look up the word in a good dictionary. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**supercharge**

> **1.1** *verb* Supply with extra energy or power.
>   
>  *'a supercharged computer'*

[From Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/supercharge)

In your example, it just means that the in-game base can be supplied with extra power.

From **super** +  **charge**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mentioned "in-game base". Could you please explain the term "base" here?

Comment: @seeeker "A place used as a centre of operations by the armed forces or others; a headquarters."  Basically, the player's HQ.  From [Oxford Dictionaries.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/base)

Comment: The term most certainly is a back-formation from "supercharger", a device installed on race cars and other powerful cars to blow air into the engine and achieve more power than otherwise possible.  This results in a vehicle that can "tear rubber" when accelerating.

Comment: @HotLicks Nice.